# message box if no record found in the database & message box max value to textbox 10

Tags: c#

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=asa-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=table1;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from worker where number='" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        { 
            textBox2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dr[1].ToString();

            MessageBox.Show("No record is found with this number >> " + textBox1.Text.ToString());
       }

    }
}
```

}

hello guys can you help me with this
i need the MessageBox to show this message if No record is found but i don't know how to include the IF with the code 
and a max numbers or letters for textbox1 is 10 if the user put more then the MessageBox (max10) will appear

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: you need to first do a check on the Textbox.Text using the length property.. then if it's > 10 return out of the button click event by doing a show message...etc.... it it passes the length check then you need to do thing check if there are records .. then  keep a counter and check outside of the while loop if the counter > 0 based on records returned from the `dr` then show the message after filling the textbox.. also what if you have 4 rows returned for example.. you would only be showing the last textbox2 and textbox3 text..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SqlDataReader.HasRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to determine whether any records were returned. like:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        textBox2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dr[1].ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No record is found with this number >> " + textBox1.Text.ToString());
}
```

But couple of other things to add:

- Use SqlParamaters instead of concatenation queries, you are open to **SQL Injection.**
- Not really sure how would you accomplish showing more than one record in `TextBox` controls you probably need a Grid or add your returned rows/recrods to a `List<T>` or `List<Worker>` where `Worker` class can have properties for columns.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) with `SqlCommand`/`SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader` as they implement `IDisposable`
- this `dr[0].ToString()` could potentially throw Null Reference Exception, research and see how you can safeguard it.

So your code more or less should look like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=asa-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=table1;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from worker where number=@Number", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", textBox1.Text);//or explicity specify type using .Add
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        //Add to List<Worker> with properties Name and Number etc
                        textBox2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                        textBox3.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No record is found with this number >> " + textBox1.Text.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would ask the OP what do they expect if there was more than 1 row returned.. look at their sql statement.. if that were the case I would recommend changing the sql command to Select on  the 2 columns where the condition equals what parameter would be replacing `textBox1.Text`

Comment: @MethodMan, that is good point, I already had specified the OP to use `Grid` for showing multiple rows, but now I added the suggestion to populate a `List<T>` and then using it.

Comment: I would personally go with a Grid but a List<T> is just as good.. thanks